# Global timeDate format in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-settings

In Django you can define how to display your timedate variables like so:

```
{{ invoice.printed|date:"D jS N 'y h:i a" }}
```

What if I wanted to use this date format across my site but have it declared in my `settings.py` as:

```
TOOLTIPS_DATE_FORMAT = "D jS N 'y h:i a"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a context processor which includes this format in all your templates:

```
from django.conf import settings

def tooltips_format(request):
    return { 'TOOLTIPS_DATE_FORMAT': settings.TOOLTIPS_DATE_FORMAT }
```

Put this in a file such as `main/context_processors.py` (or a different app if you don't have a Django app called `main`) and then add `main.context_processors.tooltips_format` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)) in your Django settings file.

You can then write in your templates:

```
{{ invoice.printed|date:TOOLTIPS_DATE_FORMAT }}
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. I thought it might be a `context processors` problem. Worked like a charm